# Разница между asyncpg и psycopg2 | Python, PostgreSQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, asyncpg

Зачем существует библиотека `asyncpg` в питоне, если **PostgreSQL** и так поддерживает множество одновременных соединений сразу? Может кто объяснить разницу, и в каких случаях какая библиотека должна использоваться?

> Просто для меня важно выяснить разницу, так как я планирую создавать дискорд ботов, где очень много `async` функций, и если `psycopg2` будет блочить скрипт как например делает `time.sleep()` в `async` функции, то меня это не устроит.

Comment: asyncpg существует для обращения к бд в асинхронном коде, psycopg2 блокировал бы event_loop из-за своей синхронной природы. Заранее стоит сказать, что по документации можно сделать вывод, что кое-как psycopg2 может работать в асинхронном режиме, но если бы это было в полной мере так, то, например, разработчики SqlAlchemy при асинхронном варианте не использовали бы асинхронный драйвер (asyncpg)

Comment: Множество соединений и асинхронный доступ - это не одно и то же. Если у вас программа асинхронная, то лучше использовать асинхронные библиотеки, конечно.

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Тогда конечно для `discord` я лучше `asyncpg` использовать буду, оно даже проще как по моему, документация довольно маленькая.

Comment: @CrazyElf, просто большинство методов `psycopg2` - блокирующие. Мне, как я понимаю, они не подойдут для бота, ведь там всё завалено в `async` функциях.

Comment: Ну да, вам нужна асинхронная библиотека, функциям которой вы могли бы делать `await`.